# How to make VoiceOver ignore UICollectionViewCell that are not visible

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, accessibility, voiceover

I have a ViewController container with 2 View Controllers inside. Both of those VC's have a UICollectionView inside. (Check video to see UI in action)
https://chewycomllc-my.sharepoint.com/:v:/g/personal/iruiz_chewy_com/ET5cHAObgy5DmOWop4KRtV4BXHbwLEs1BgqX4udqJGu_xQ?e=f9VQ1a

When the top VC makes a selection on the collectionView, the bottom VC select the corresponding cell taking the full width (only 1 cell seen at a time in the bottom VC). (See image to visualize UI setup)
[image]

When I select the second cell on the top VC, the bottom VC shows the second cell. The problem is that when VoiceOver is focused on the last cell of the top VC it navigates to the first UI element in the top left of the first cell (index 0) instead of the top left element of the 2nd cell. (See GIF to see issue)
https://chewycomllc-my.sharepoint.com/:i:/g/personal/iruiz_chewy_com/EW7SVm4S74tEjMgKME2vK58BBtaA1WYEyL0_wjzUYkWiig?e=lylo9O

I tried disabling accessibility on the cells, the VC, the collectionView. I also tried posting a notification that the screen or the layout change. None of it worked as expected.

The Yelp app does this correctly when you are looking the images of a restaurant.

Comment: what is your question exactly ?

Comment: I was hoping the title would make that clear: `How to make VoiceOver ignore UICollectionViewCell that are not visible`. Put another way, I want VoiceOver to only navigate into the cell currently seen (the one that has the ContentViewController) and ignore the rest as if they didn't exist.

Comment: it really depends on how you coded the accessibility of your collectionView. I suggest you take a look at the WWDC video 'Deliver an exceptional accessibility experience' perfectly summarized here : http://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios-wwdc-18230.html

Comment: I watched the video, read that article and downloaded the sample code but none of it touches on this specific problem. My issue is different in that I need VoiceOver to navigate the ContentViewController inside cell centered at the moment, but ignore all others.

Comment: @Ivan Have you found any solution. I am also facing the same problem.